# Append unique list items to the DOM in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a to-do list with React and have got pretty close. I'm adding `<li>` elements to the dom when I click the button, but the text I put in the input field is being set to all the `<li>`s. I'm new to React and a bit confused.

How could I do this? See code and link to codepen:

[Codepen live example](https://codepen.io/ryan_pixelers/pen/gLQQOx)

```
var ListContainer = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      numChildren: 0,
      text: null
    };
  },
  onAddChild: function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('itemAdder').value;
    console.log(inputValue);
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1,
      text: inputValue
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    var children = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i++) {
      children.push(<Item key={'item_' + i} number={i} text={this.state.text}/>);
    };
    return (
      <List addChild={this.onAddChild}>
        {children}
      </List>
    );
  }
});

var List = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="listContainer">
        <p><input type="text" name="itemAdder" id="itemAdder" /></p>
        <p><button type="button" onClick={this.props.addChild}>Add another item</button></p>
        <ul>
          {this.props.children}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var Item = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var key = this.props.index;
    return (
      <li>{this.props.text}</li>
    );
  }
});

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div id="main" className="page-wrap">
        <ListContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The Problem**

You are very close but the problem is that when you are constructing the children list in the render method, for every item you say that is value should be equal to the text key inside the state. This is why all the `<li>`s are rendering the same value.

**Solution**

The design of the state of your component is incorrect. This is how the state should be:

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      numChildren: 0,
      list: [] //this will an array of objects
    };
}
```

The onAddChild method should be like this:

```
onAddChild: function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('itemAdder').value;
    console.log(inputValue);
    var newList = this.state.list.slice(); //Avoiding state mutation
    newList.push(inputValue)
    this.setState({
      numChildren: this.state.numChildren + 1,
      list: newList
    });
}
```

After this when you costruct the children array in your render method associate the corresponding list values according to the index of the for loop like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.state.numChildren; i++) {
  children.push(<Item key={'item_' + i} number={i} text={this.state.list[i]}/>);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new Item, you are not saving the previous added values, instead you are overriding the value itself.

You should keep an array of strings in your state.

```
onAddChild: function() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById('itemAdder').value;

    this.setState({
        items: [...this.state.items, inputValue]
    });
}
```

The numChildren variable is not necessary, since you can get it from items.length

Comment: but I don't have a state property called items. how  would I do that?

Comment: You should redesign the state of your component (adjusting the getInitialState function)